Microsoft Surface Precision Mouse wheel stops working after a few mins
I have a Microsoft Surface Precision Mouse.
When I start the computer and log in, the mouse works and its wheel works.
But after a while the wheel stops working, but the rest of the mouse functions.
When I run xev I don't see any events for button 4 and 5 (wheel) at that point, though intially in the first mins after logging in, the events are there on xev for button 4 and 5.
If I run sudo systemctl restart bluetooth to restart the bluetooth, then the wheel starts working again for a few mins before it stops again.
Not sure what is causing it to stop. On the screen events related to BTLE Precision Mouse disconnected and reconneded just before the mouse wheel stops working.
Not sure how to troubleshoot it any further.
Has anyone faced a similar issue? Any ideas how to see what is causing the wheel to stop working?

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

@guiverc ack. I can drop the reference to Debian from the question and replace it with Ubuntu. The same issue is present there as well.

You'll need to provide release details then, as Ubuntu releases have kernel stack choice & you've not told us what you're actually running (kernel will change kernel modules; kernel modules commonly called drivers).  Also you've not said if you tried ubuntu-drivers autoinstall which is the first thing to the ensure you system has correct drivers installed; please paste that detail (command and results) in your question.
